# How to write vba code for IF function between minimum and maximum limit of a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I was writing the vba code for a condition. If i want to highlight specific age between 20 to 35 year along with systolic blood pressure 110-140 (normal systolic range) and diastolic pressure 70-90 (normal diastolic range) in a sample as "Normal" otherwise "Risky". Please help

Comment: Please update your question small snap-shot of your data layout.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your desired output.

Comment: Please update your question with your current code attempt.

Comment: please share your code .

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided much information but here is a starter for you:

```
Sub MyFunction()

If age > 20 And age < 35 Then
    If bloodPressure > 110 And bloodPressure <= 140 Then
        'Do something as Normal range
    ElseIf bloodPressure > 70 And bloodPressure <= 90 Then
        'Do something else as Risky range
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I'd recommend you read about Flow Control and Decision Structures. The Microsoft Documentation is a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/

Cheers Chris